# Any reasons against a very high value in proxy_send_timeout for websockets?

Tags: nginx, timeout, websocket

I use nginx as an ingress controller in Kubernetes.

I have a websocket connection between 2 applications which you should stay open *indefinitely*. There is a reconnect mechanism but that should be avoided as much as possible.

Currently, the nginx config looks something like this (omitted non-relevant parts):

```
location / {

    proxy_set_header     Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header     Connection        "Upgrade";

    proxy_send_timeout   3600s;
    proxy_read_timeout   3600s;
}
```

Are there any arguments against picking a very high value for the timeouts, let's say 1 year?